# Inventario con Productos de Precio Variable

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap, ajax

He creado un sistema php/mysql para despacho con inventario de productos y el problema que tengo es que **no sé cómo calcular el costo del despacho cuando tengo ingresos del mismo producto con distintos precios.**

Mi base datos esta compuesta de la siguiente manera:

[image: BD]

**Tabla Producto**: Solo Mantiene id, nombre y cantidad de los productos en el inventario

**Tabla Ingreso**: Registra los ingresos de productos con su respectivo precio al momento de comprar al proveedor (Unica tabla que registra precios)

**Tabla Devoprov**: Registra las devoluciones al proveedor

**Tabla Transacciones:** Registra los despachos con una id, centro al cual se despacha, id del producto que despacha, cantidad del producto que despacha, comentario, responsable, fecha y id_tra registra un 1 para despacho y 2 para devolucion.

Con php registro de esta manera los despachos

```
  if(isset($_POST['btnnewsal'])){   // preguntar si presiono el boton

     //Array Productos
    require_once 'config.php';
    for ($i=0; $i < count($_POST['itemNo']); $i++ ) {
    $idventa = $_POST['venta'];
    $idpro = $_POST['itemNo'][$i];
    $res = $_SESSION['nombre'];
    $cre = "NOW()";
    $comentario = $_POST['notes'];
    $centro = $_POST['cbocod'];
    $canpro = $_POST['quantity'][$i];
    $qryUpt = "INSERT INTO transacciones VALUES ('$idventa','$centro','$idpro','$canpro','$comentario','$res',$cre,1)";
    mysqli_query($con,$qryUpt) or die(mysqli_error());
    }

    //Disminuir inventario
    for ($i=0; $i < count($_POST['itemNo']); $i++ ) {
    $idpro = $_POST['itemNo'][$i];
    $canpro = $_POST['quantity'][$i];
    $qryUpt = "UPDATE producto SET uni_pro = uni_pro-'$canpro' WHERE id_pro='$idpro'";
    mysqli_query($con,$qryUpt) or die(mysqli_error());
    }

}
```

Mi formulario para rescatar los productos luce asi (despacho.php)

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="despacho.php">
        <div class="form-group">
               <label for="cbocod" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Centro Medico:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select class="form-control select2" id="cbocod" name="cbocod" style="width: 50%;">
                    <?php
                    $u->llenarcombocentros();
                     ?>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
        <div class="form-group">
               <label for="cbocod" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Codigo Transaccion:</label>
              <div class="col-md-1">
                <input type="text" style="text-align: center;" class="form-control" id="venta" name="venta" value="<?php $u->contarventas(); ?>" readonly>
                  </div>
                </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <table id="vender" width="90%" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="2%"><input id="check_all" class="formcontrol" type="checkbox"/></th>
                        <th width="15%">Codigo</th>
                        <th width="35%">Nombre</th> <!-- 34% -->
                        <th width="10%">Stock</th>
                        <th width="10%">Cantidad</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" data-type="id_pro" name="itemNo[]" id="itemNo_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt changesNo" autocomplete="off" required></td>
                        <td><input type="text" data-type="nom_pro" name="itemName[]" id="itemName_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt changesNo" autocomplete="off" required></td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="stock[]" id="stock_1" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" readonly></td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_1" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" required></td>





                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <button class="btn btn-danger delete" type="button">- Borrar</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success addmore" type="button">+ Agregar Producto</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br><br>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="notes" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Comentarios:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="notes" name="notes" placeholder="Comentarios">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11">
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Limpiar</button>
                <button type="submit" id="btnnewsal" name="btnnewsal" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Despachar</button>
        </div><!-- /.box-footer -->
    </div>
    </form>
```

Y este formulario se rellena con este javascript que funciona con jqueyUI y ajax

auto.js

```
$(document).on('focus','.autocomplete_txt',function(){
type = $(this).data('type');

if(type =='id_pro' )autoTypeNo=0;
if(type =='nom_pro' )autoTypeNo=1;


$(this).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'ajax.php',
            dataType: "json",
            method: 'post',
            data: {
               name_startsWith: request.term,
               type: type
            },
             success: function( data ) {
                 response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                    var code = item.split("|");
                    return {
                        label: code[autoTypeNo],
                        value: code[autoTypeNo],
                        data : item
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    autoFocus: true,            
    minLength: 0,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        var names = ui.item.data.split("|");                        
        id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
        id = id_arr.split("_");
        $('#itemNo_'+id[1]).val(names[0]);
        $('#itemName_'+id[1]).val(names[1]);
        $('#stock_'+id[1]).val(names[2]);
        $('#quantity_'+id[1]).val(1);

        }               
}); });
```

y mi ajax.php luce de la siguiente manera

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
if(!empty($_POST['type'])){
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $name = $_POST['name_startsWith'];
    $query = "SELECT id_pro, nom_pro, uni_pro FROM producto where       UPPER($type) LIKE '".strtoupper($name)."%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $name = $row['id_pro'].'|'.$row['nom_pro'].'|'.$row['uni_pro'];
        array_push($data, $name);
    }   
    echo json_encode($data);exit;
}
```

Espero que de verdad me puedan ayudar a poder mostrar el costo del despacho con los distintos tipos de precio que puedan haber para un mismo producto por que de verdad llevo días en esto y no se me logra ocurrir como hacerlo.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes , te sugiero que pongas que consulta SQL  has intentado para obtener el costo de despacho. Saludos

Comment: llegue a esto: "SELECT calendar.datefield AS DATE, IFNULL(SUM(transacciones.can_ven),0) AS total_sales FROM transacciones RIGHT JOIN calendar ON (DATE(transacciones.cre_dep) = calendar.datefield) WHERE calendar.datefield BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end' AND transacciones.id_tra=1 GROUP BY DATE" pero lo unico que me muestra es la cantidad de productos vendidos por dia

Comment: ese modelo de datos lo podes cambiar o no ?

Comment: si obvio, estoy buscando cualquier solucion para mi problema

Comment: Puedes intentar agrupar por productos en la tabla ingresos, con un Group BY

Comment: pero al momento de hacer esto, solo me muestra el ingreso con el precio mas antiguo

Answer (score 1):

Creo que si tienes muchos productos con el mismo nombre pero de diferente precio, los cuales no haces ninguna diferencia en tu base de datos como manejar un código o relacionar los productos en una tabla, va a ser complicado que puedas hacer una sumatoria, que es lo que entendí con costo del despacho.
Quieres saber cuanto es lo que ha producido el despacho, la sucursal, o equivalente.
También entiendo que tienes una tabla de inventarios, por lo tanto, lo que buscas no es la cantidad en existencia, sino saber que diferenciar al momento de hacer la sumatoria.
Mi recomendación agrupalos para sacar totales.

Comment: entiendo lo de la agrupacion, he investigado mucho al respecto y me recomendaron usar el metodo FIFO para esto. No se si es lo correcto

Comment: Creo que depende del objetivo que quieras lograr y no tanto como una técnica.